# Return value by lookup from multiple value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

We constantly receive offers from suppliers and requests from customers. The problem is that customers and suppliers usually have several different identifiers for the same product. Like this:

customer requests
[image]

supplier offers
[image]

In order see the matches between the offers and requests, I need to create a sheet with the unique products with the Product Name and Main ID we want to use. Next to the Main IDs, I need to enter all the alternative IDs that I met in offers and requests. Something like this:

product_data
[image]

My question is what is the best formula to make google sheet look for the IDs in offers/requests from column C to column I of product_data sheet (from ALT ID 1 to ALT ID 7 )and based on that, return the MAIN ID of the product in offers/request?  like this:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). You might find this easy to handle with `vlookup()` if you changed your "wide" product_data table to a "tall" table where the alt IDs are all in column A and the relevant main ID is in column B, repeated on multiple rows as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=QUERY(
    'ID-LookUp'!$A$2:$I$3,
    "SELECT B WHERE " &
    REGEXREPLACE(
        CONCATENATE(
            ArrayFormula(
                SPLIT(
                    "B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I",
                    ","
                ) & " = " &
                CHAR(
                    34
                ) & A2 &
                CHAR(
                    34
                ) & " OR "
            )
        ),
        "OR $",
        ""
    ),
    0
)
```

#### Explanation

Alright the `REGEXREPLACE` thing first. We are basically first generating the WHERE clause for the `QUERY` function there. we take the array which just has B through I then append to each `= "ID" OR`. The ID part we get from the A column. We then use `REGEXREPLACE` to remove the redundant "OR" at the end.

We move now to the main `QUERY` function. We select the data only (A2:I3 not A1:I3). This is to make sure that the header doesn't show up. Next we select B since it contains the Main ID we want to return. We then append the string and done.

Comment: Dear David, 
thank you for your reply! Unfortunately something is still missing from the formula

Comment: Dear David, 
thank you for your reply! 
Unfortunately something is still missing from the formula, the following #VALUE error occurs: "Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered "<ID "WHEREB" at line 1, column 10. Was expecting one of: <EOF> "where" ... "group" ... "pivot" ... "order" ... "skipping" ... "limit" ... "offset" ... "label"... "format"... "options" "," ... "*" ... "+" ... "-" ... "/" ... "%" ... "+" ... "-" ...
Can you please help me with what else to add to the query?

Comment: the error is saying that there is `WHEREB` somewhere in the function, though that seems strange since there is a space in the string. If you are able to provide a copy of your gsheet, that would help immensely. @TamásHéjja